# MicroService Testing - Don't Have Credit/Debit card

Tags: microservices

I don't have a credit or debit card. Is there is any place where i can get my microservices deployed for free for testing.

I wanted to learn but AWS asks for credit card info for signup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to test your microservices in a cloud environment you may need a credit/debit card at least for major cloud providers. You will not be charged as many of the AWS services are within the free tier limits.

The other option I feel is you can go for a docker container, which you can install on your local machine and test your micro services on the same. Dockers are pretty easy to install and deploy and are free of cost.